# How do I retrive Quill text editor text using Delta

Tags: javascript, php, quill

I am using the quill text editor in a php based web-app and I need to retrieve the contents of the text editor as a string with the HTML included but the docs are a little sparse on this subject. Ultimately I want to write that data to a database.

This is how I tried to get the content

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an Des...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
var delta = quill.getContents();
var text = editor.getText();
```

Comment: Where is the variable `editor` defined?

Comment: actually I see the documentation of Quill.js

Comment: and think that editor is Super Global scope particular in this library!

Comment: I also tried `var text = quill.getText();`